# .Net core controller tempdata add/remove

Tags: upgrade, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, tempdata

Implementing ExceptionFilterAttribute OnException method and need to redirect
The old implementation (.Net 48) was

```
exceptionContext.Controller.TempData.Remove(""); 
exceptionContext.Controller.TempData.Add("");//exception message is added
exceptionContext.Controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);
```

For the redirect I guess I can:

```
exceptionContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(url);//Is this correct?
```

Please suggest alternate for the remove and add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .net 6,there's no `exceptionContext.Controller.TempData` if you want to access TempData in your ExceptionFilter,you could try to inject the TempdataDictionaryFactory into the filter

For example, I tried as below:

```
public class MyExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly ITempDataDictionaryFactory _tempDataDictionaryFactory;




        public MyExceptionFilter(ITempDataDictionaryFactory tempDataDictionaryFactory)
        {
            _tempDataDictionaryFactory = tempDataDictionaryFactory;
        }



       public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            var tempData = _tempDataDictionaryFactory.GetTempData(context.HttpContext);
            tempData.Add("key", "value");
            
            context.Result = new RedirectToActionResult("Error", "Home", null);
        }
    }
```

in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(x=>x.Filters.Add(typeof(MyExceptionFilter)));
```

The Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ruikai Feng... The redirection in my case is like this: var url = exceptionContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(); and the Redirection is to the url, will the above RedirectionToActionResult work here?

Comment: You could try RedirectResult("url")；